# Rich Text Content Breaks TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

So I'm working with some content using TinyMCE, and unfortunately it seems that sometimes, the content put into it (RTE blob data from the database) is breaking the script.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49t8m/1/) of it in action.

I use a function to set the `tinymce.init()`, and it works fine, however it seems that something in the RTE data completely breaks the textareas.

Here is the script:

```
function initMCE(e) {
    tinymce.init({
        mode:"exact",
        elements:e,
        plugins:"paste",
        height:300,
        width:750,
        toolbar: "bold italic underline, bullist, numlist superscript subscript",
        menubar:false,
        valid_elements : "em/i,li,ul,ol,u,strong/b,sup,sub,p"
    });
}
initMCE("definition");
initMCE("consent");
initMCE("penalty");
```

And the HTML is simple but:

```
<textarea name="definition" id="definition"></textarea>
<textarea name="consent" id="consent"></textarea>
<textarea name="penalty" id="penalty"></textarea>
```

See the content in the fiddle that's breaking it. Is there a way to protect my script from input such as this?

Here is the error as well:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js:6
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [bug in TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4409).

Reproduction: http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/6t25w/

A quick fix for this is just make sure there is a space before the comments

```
<textarea name="definition" id="definition"> <!-- some comment --></textarea>
<textarea name="consent" id="consent"></textarea>
<textarea name="penalty" id="penalty"></textarea>
```

[JSFiddle Fix Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49t8m/3/)

Added a comment to the bug about it still being in 4.1

### Other Fixes:

**Add `code` to the toolbar list**

```
toolbar: "code bold italic underline, bullist, numlist superscript subscript"
```

**Patch code**

Error seems to be from one of the statements filtering out `data-mce-bogus` elements

```
//From Formatter.js source
parents = Tools.grep(parents, function(node) {
    return !node.getAttribute('data-mce-bogus');
});
```

Since comments do not have a `getAttribute` function, it errors out. So adding a check for `getAttribute` fixes it

```
return (node.getAttribute && !node.getAttribute('data-mce-bogus'));
```

[Tinymce 4.1.2 Minified Version Patch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nf9evpgqo5kxqik/tinymce-4.1.2.min.patch)

**Patch source** (requires node.js to build)

Get tinymce source from github, [***patch Formatter.js***](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mt5ar8k8iru8x6o/Formatter.js.patch), and build

```bash
git clone git://github.com/tinymce/tinymce.git ./tinymce
git checkout -b patched 416e35737aed2af60eff69887bb7bf33cc3b4bc8
wget -O Formatter.js.patch https://www.dropbox.com/s/mt5ar8k8iru8x6o/Formatter.js.patch?dl=1
patch -p1 < Formatter.js.patch
npm i -g jake
npm i
jake
```

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce